# Proof of a Proposition on Partitions and Equivalence Classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, set-partition

I stumbled upon a seemingly rudimentary proposition that I am having trouble writing out a proof for. The proposition goes something like,

> > **Proposition:**  If $\{A_i|i\in I\}$ is a partition of $\mathcal A$, then there is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal A$ whose
> >     equivalence clases are precisely the sets $A_i, i \in I$.
>
> Where $I$ is some indexing set.

How do I prove the statement ? I can't even decide on a good place to start.

Comment: To be honest, I can't wrap my head around the proposition at all. How is it that no matter what kind of partition I choose to work with, I **always** end up with some collection of equivalence classes?

Comment: Write down carefully the definition of an equivalence relation. Write down carefully what this equivalence relation would have to satisfy in order for this to be true.

Comment: BTW, and very importantly in some contexts, the other direction is true as well, so that we have a 1-1 correspondence between all equivalence relations and all partitions on a given set.

Comment: oh, I got it now. Thanks

Comment: [Relation induced by partition](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Relation_Induced_by_Partition) at ProofWiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $I$ is an arbitrary "index set" then a set-vauled function $$f:\quad I\to {\cal P}(A)\ ,\quad i\mapsto A_i\ ,$$ where ${\cal P}(A)$ denotes the power set of $A$, is called a *family of subsets of* $A$ and is denoted by $(A_i)_{i\in I}\ $. Such a family is called a *partition of* $A$, if (i) all $A_i$ are nonempty, (ii) the $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint, i.e., $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ when $i\ne j$, and (iii) $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i=A$.

Given a partition $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of  $A$,  for each $x\in A$ *there is a unique* $i\in I$ such that $x\in A_i$. This defines a function $\iota:  A\to I$ which returns for each $x\in  A$ the unique $i$ with $x\in A_i$.

Now it is easy to check that
$$x\sim y\quad:\Leftrightarrow\quad \iota(x)=\iota(y)$$
defines an equivalence relation on $ A$ whose equivalence classes are exactly the $A_i$.

Comment: You say that "$\ldots$ for each $x∈A$ there is a **unique** $i∈I$ such that $x∈A_i \ldots$" Doesn't this mean that there has to be as many partitions as the order of $I$? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bidit Acharya: Yes; see my edit.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant "Doesn't this mean that there has to be as many partitions as the order of $A$ ?"

Comment: @Bidit Acharia: We are talking about just *one* partition $(A_i)_{i\in I}$. The number of parts (= the cardinality of $I$) is at least one and at most as large as the cardinality of $A$.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what to do.  Define $x\sim y$ iff for some $i$ in the index set, $x,y\in A_i$.  This is an equivalence relation.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. What do you mean by "for some $i\in A_i$"?

Comment: Also, do I define an arbitrary equivalence relation? Could you please elaborate, I am a high school student. I hope you understand.

Comment: Check it out.  Choose $x\in\mathcal{A}$.  Then there is some $i$ so $x\in A_i$.  Thus, $x\sim x$.  Suppose that $x\sim y$.  Then for some $i$, $x, y \in A_i$ (x and y belong to the same element of the partition).  Thus $y, x\in A_i$; therefore $y\sim x$.  You can develop transitivity similarly.

Comment: I have edited the definition of the equivalence relation so that hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: I have clarified things by adding "in the index set".  Yeah, my faulty typesetting made it appear that $i\in\mathcal{A}$.